# why bash read command create a loop-local variable?

Tags: bash, pipe, subshell

I wrote following bash script. The read command creates variable `var`.
if `$var==5` then break loop.

```bash
    seq 10 | while read -r var
    do
      echo "read: $var"
      if [[ $var == 5 ]]; then
        echo "break loop: $var"
        break
      fi
    done
    
    echo "after loop: $var"
```

Here is the output

```
read: 1
read: 2
read: 3
read: 4
read: 5
break loop: 5
after loop:
```

My question is: why after loop, `$var` is empty?

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/024 (I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable isn't loop-local, and everything related to `read` and loops here are just red herrings. The behavior you're seeing is because the pipe starts a subshell. If you get rid of the pipe and run this code instead:

```bash
    while read -r var
    do
      echo "read: $var"
      if [[ $var == 5 ]]; then
        echo "break loop: $var"
        break
      fi
    done < <(seq 10)
    
    echo "after loop: $var"
```

Then it will print this instead:

```
read: 1
read: 2
read: 3
read: 4
read: 5
break loop: 5
after loop: 5
```

Comment: Another alternative is to run `shopt -s lastpipe`